# Changing value of variable in a file

Tags: java, user-interface, variables

I am trying to write a code in java which can read a variable from a .txt file or .rul file and change its content as specified by user. Basically, i'll add this snippet of code into the UI, where user will give new value for the variable stored in file.

Example: Consider if variable name is 'x'and value assigned to it is 10 then its assigned will change to 'x=20' if user give value as 20.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: sounds like a properties file

Comment: it can be any type of file @ScaryWombat

Comment: So what's ya question then?

Comment: I need to detect a variable and change the value assigned to it @ScaryWombat

Comment: Let's see what you've tried so far. It almost sounds like you're looking for something like a Windows type .ini (initialization) file.

Comment: I have a setup.rul file in that file a variable called MD_VER was there which has some value 1.2.2.0. I need to change the MD_VER=1.2.2.0 to the version number specified by user @DevilsHnd. Earlier I was using the code to find and replace which finds 1.2.2.0 and replace the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Properties Class to store and load key-value pairs from a file:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: It didn't worked :(

Comment: What did not work?